# Stop non-alphanumeric characters from being posted - PHP

Tags: php

I'm attempting to check an array to see if it contains any special characters once it has been posted to the PHP script. If the string does contain special characters, I'm wanting to display an error asking the user to remove them before continuing to post the form.

The issue I'm having is, my script isn't detecting the special characters.

I feel like I'm missing the obvious here.

If anyone could shed some light it'd be much appreciated.

```
$special = preg_match_all('/[^\da-z]/i', $caption[0]);
if($special !== false){
echo "Make sure you haven't got any special characters in your captions.";
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved:**

After looping through each item in the array using a foreach loop and then producing a key to identify each item by nesting it within a while loop.

```
$p = 0;
while($p < $imgCount){
foreach($captions as $index => $max){
if (preg_match_all('~[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+~', $max[$p]))
{
  echo 'Remove any special characters from your captions.';
  exit();
}
}
$p++;
}
```